# What are the extra digits when printing floating point numbers in decimal format in C?

Tags: c, runtime, libc

If I use printf with a high precision and print a floating point number, I get extra numbers beyond what is represented by the type.

For example:

```
const double x = 1.0 / 3.0;
printf("%.50f\n", x);
```

The result is:

`0.33333333333333331482961625624739099293947219848633`

And x in memory is 0x3FD5555555555555. If I convert the floating point representation manually (with a calculator), I get the following instead.

`0.3333333333333333`

Where do the extra digits come from?

Comment: Your calculator rounded. The actual value of that floating point-value mantissa times 2^exponent is close to 0.33333333333333331482961625624739099293947219848633. With my machine and no rounding, I have 0.333333333333333314829616256247390992939472198486328125 as the exact decimal representation for mantissa * 2^exp. You actually have an analogous issue in base 10 - 0.3333333333333333(00000000) is not an exact value either. The exact value has endlessly repeating 3s.

Comment: See [Is floating point math broken?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-floating-point-math-broken)

Comment: If your calculator could show 50 digits, it would show something similar.

Comment: The fraction 1/3 cannot be exactly represented in either decimal or binary. You are getting the nearest representable value. The computer doesn't *know* you intended it to be exactly 1/3 when it outputs it.

Comment: Is the tolerance/level of rounding defined somewhere? Since it can vary from platforms

Comment: If you print out enough digits, the trailing digits will be zero.

Comment: @ValeriaSuarez It is defined by the nature of the IEEE 754 representation

Comment: @ValeriaSuarez if the floating point type isn't providing enough significance, use a larger type. But the same will apply and you can think about *why* you need such minutely exact values. Generally, you should treat floating point values as approximate. Only a discrete amount of the infinite range of values can be exactly stored in a finite space, so the problem is never going to go away.